# Problems reading xml file with Chinese characters using UTF-8 encoding in RStudio

Tags: xml, encoding, utf-8, rstudio

I want to read a .xml file which looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<province name="北京市" id="11">
  <city name="市辖区" id="110100000000">
    <county name="东城区" id="110101000000">
      <town name="珍珠泉乡" id="110229214000">
        <village name="珍珠泉乡社区居委会" id="110229214001" type="220"/>
        <village name="珍珠泉村委会" id="110229214200" type="210"/>
        <village name="称沟湾村委会" id="110229214201" type="220"/>
        <village name="庙梁村委会" id="110229214202" type="220"/>
        <village name="下水沟村委会" id="110229214203" type="220"/>
        <village name="上水沟村委会" id="110229214204" type="220"/>
        <village name="下花楼村委会" id="110229214205" type="220"/>
        <village name="八亩地村委会" id="110229214206" type="220"/>
        <village name="转山子村委会" id="110229214207" type="220"/>
        <village name="水泉子村委会" id="110229214208" type="220"/>
        <village name="双金草村委会" id="110229214209" type="220"/>
        <village name="小川村委会" id="110229214210" type="220"/>
        <village name="小铺村委会" id="110229214211" type="220"/>
        <village name="仓米道村委会" id="110229214212" type="220"/>
        <village name="南天门村委会" id="110229214213" type="220"/>
        <village name="桃条沟村委会" id="110229214214" type="220"/>
      </town>
    </county>
  </city>
</province>
```

I set the system locale to be simplified Chinese using `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", locale="Chinese (Simplified)")`, and read the document using XML package with UTF-8 encoding `doc = xmlParse(files[i], encoding = "UTF-8", useInternalNodes = TRUE)`, but when I look at `doc`, the Chinese characters are not properly displayed:

```
<village id="110229214001" type="220" name="鐝嶇彔娉変埂绀惧尯灞呭浼?/>
        <village id="110229214200" type="210" name="鐝嶇彔娉夋潙濮斾細"/>
        <village id="110229214201" type="220" name="绉版矡婀炬潙濮斾細"/>
        <village id="110229214202" type="220" name="搴欐鏉戝浼?/>
        <village id="110229214203" type="220" name="涓嬫按娌熸潙濮斾細"/>
        <village id="110229214204" type="220" name="涓婃按娌熸潙濮斾細"/>
        <village id="110229214205" type="220" name="涓嬭姳妤兼潙濮斾細"/>
        <village id="110229214206" type="220" name="鍏憨鍦版潙濮斾細"/>
        <village id="110229214207" type="220" name="杞北瀛愭潙濮斾細"/>
        <village id="110229214208" type="220" name="姘存硥瀛愭潙濮斾細"/>
        <village id="110229214209" type="220" name="鍙岄噾鑽夋潙濮斾細"/>
        <village id="110229214210" type="220" name="灏忓窛鏉戝浼?/>
        <village id="110229214211" type="220" name="灏忛摵鏉戝浼?/>
        <village id="110229214212" type="220" name="浠撶背閬撴潙濮斾細"/>
        <village id="110229214213" type="220" name="鍗楀ぉ闂ㄦ潙濮斾細"/>
        <village id="110229214214" type="220" name="妗冩潯娌熸潙濮斾細"/>
```

I also tried to set the system locale to `English_United States.1252`, but the problem remains the same.
One strange thing is that, when I use some functions over `doc`, for example `xmlRoot(doc)` or `getNodeSet(doc,"//village")[1]`, the Chinese characters are displayed correctly. But not for all functions, if I use `xmlAttrs(getNodeSet(doc,"//village")[[1]])`, it has problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try xml linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication49
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml"; 
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);
            var z = reader.ReadLine();

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(reader);

            var results = doc.Descendants("village").Select(x => new
            {
                name = (string)x.Attribute("name"),
                id = (long)x.Attribute("id"),
                type = (int)x.Attribute("type")
            }).ToList();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I googled a bit and it seems to be LINQ queries. Where should I put in and run these commands? I'm new to this.

Comment: Yes it is an XML Linq (XDocument class).  Just treat code like any other code.  Nothing special is needed.

Comment: I have error message when I tried to run the code in R 'Error: unexpected symbol in "using System"'. Do I need to install some packages?

Comment: My code is for Visual Studio c#.  Not rstdio.  Sorry.

Comment: I see, no problem. Good to know that, something new that I can learn :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be the problem with encoding. My aim is to extract the village information from the xml file. After I extracted the information, when I check the encoding of the village name column, it shows that the encoding is `"unknown"`. So I added one command to make the encoding of that column as "UTF-8" and it works. My code is shown below.

But I still don't know why the encoding is unknown. I have already specified `encoding="UTF-8` at the very beginning when I read the xml file using `xmlParse()`. Anyone knows why? Did I make any mistake when I read the xml file?

```
> village = as.data.frame(t(xmlSApply(doc["/province/city/county/town/village"],xmlAttrs)),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
> View(village)
> Encoding(village[1,"name"])
[1] "unknown"
> Encoding(village[,"name"])="UTF-8"   #added this line and the display is fine now
```